# how to save .cdr(Corel Draw) to a pdf file to the same resolution as the .cdr file?

Tags: image, file, pdf, resolution, coreldraw

I am trying to save a .cdr file to pdf, but every time it's converting me with lower-resolution than the original .cdr file, what settings can I do while saving the file to remain the same resolution?

I tried to save the .cdr file to png at the same resolution, but is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PDF does not have one resolution they are variable unitless.

So what resolution do you desire?.

- Set the PDF  as media perhaps 8 inches wide OK
- Keep unaltered default as a basic resolution of 1440 twips per inch.
- Place an image or points on the page at 200 twips per point = 720 dpi
- Ensure an image of 7200 x7200 pixels is in one square inch and it will look like 7200 DPI

The simplest way to decide is if source is 300 DPI then place it at 1:1 so that each 1 media inch = 1 source inch that will be if not scaled 4.166666666666667 pixels per point (ppp)